# How to auto generate grails code for "create" view that will allow us to add multiple phone numbers in the Contact create.gsp itself?

Tags: grails

```
class Contact { 
    String firstName 
    String lastName 

    static hasMany = [ phones:Phone ] 
} 

class Phone { 
    String number 

    static belongsTo = [ contact:Contact ] 
}
```

Is there a way to auto generate the create view that will allow us to add multiple phone numbers in the Contact create.gsp itself?

Answer (score 0):

This post [Grails one-to-many dynamic forms](http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/) can help you to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @Benoit Wickramarachi. But I want to know is there any way to generate similar piece of code upon generate-all or upon some other command or by altering templates or by using any plugin?

Comment: No, actually the generate-all is doing the basic CRUD interface but then you need to tweak it a little for your needs.